# Docker Toolbox setup fails on Windows 8.1

Tags: docker, windows-8.1

After (successfully, I believe) installing the Docker Toolbox, I get the following error:

```
$ docker ps
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.26/containers/json: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
```

Also, when I try to run the docker quickstart terminal, it just prints the following error:

```
Docker Machine is not installed. Please re-run the Toolbox Installer and try aga
in.

Looks like something went wrong in step 'Looking for vboxmanage.exe'... Press an
y key to continue...
```

I searched through the docker troubleshooting but didn't find any hint. 
I tried installing the toolbox both with and without checking the `"Install VirtualBox with NDIS5 driver [default NDIS6]"` checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

1. Check if the docker machine exists. Command to check this below.

   `docker-machine ls`

If you still get error then execute step 2 below. If you see any machine listed and it has `STATE` stopped then execute  `docker-machine start machine_name`  eg.  `docker-machine start default`

2. This step helps you to create a docker-machine.

   `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`

Answer (score 1):

I also face some problems like you and I troubleshoot the problem with the following steps in window 8.1.

- Install Docker Toolbox
- REGENERATE CERTIFICATES

  > $ docker-machine regenerate-certs default
  >
  > Regenerate TLS machine certs?  Warning: this is irreversible. (y/n): y
  >
  > Regenerating TLS certificates
- Create new machine default

  > $ docker-machine create default
  >
  > Note: It may take a few minutes for downloading **boot2docker.iso** file.
- UPGRADE docker-machine (Optional)

  > $ docker-machine upgrade
- START Docker Quickstart Terminal (or) Run start.sh file under the location => **C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox**
- RUN HELLOWORLD

  > $ docker run hello-world

I hope it will help you :-)